# Cannot change display resolution from 640x480

Tags: pi-2, display

I have a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B. which I use to auomate a couple of things in the house. I connected a relatively old Full HD display which has VGA input, by using a HDMI to VGA adaptor.

The display works well, except I cannot change the resolution. It is supposed to support Full HD, but instead I get a funny 640x480 which does not use all the monitor space.

I tried editing manually the `/boot/config.txt` file with the specific configuration:

```
hdmi_mode=16
```

(that is supposed to be 1080p)

This did not make any change.

Also, tried `raspi-config`, which in fact modifies the `config.txt` file in a similar way, but without any success.

Relevant output:

```
$ tvservice -m CEA
Group CEA has 5 modes:
           mode 1: 640x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:25MHz progressive 
           mode 2: 720x480 @ 60Hz 4:3, clock:27MHz progressive 
           mode 3: 720x480 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:27MHz progressive 
  (native) mode 4: 1280x720 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:74MHz progressive 
  (native) mode 16: 1920x1080 @ 60Hz 16:9, clock:148MHz progressive
```

How can I change the resolution so that I can use the Full HD display optimally?

Comment: Did you set hdmi_group=1 ? https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/config-txt/video.md

Comment: @CoderMike Yes, I did...